# save and restore tkinter UI state using serialized Tk widget object

Tags: python, tkinter

in a Tkinter app, I'm trying to implement a UI save and load feature(for example if the user exits the app, the next time he will open it it will open in the same state it was before closing).
please read comments on `load_state` function.

```py
def save_state(self):
    saveFileWithExplorer(jsonpickle.encode(self.root), title='Save UI State', defaultextension=".state",
                         initialfile="schema tool UI state")

def load_state(self):
    stateText = openAndReadFileWithExplorer(title='Choose UI STATE file', filetypes=(("STATE files", "*.state"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    state = jsonpickle.decode(stateText)
    # what i've tried:
    # 1. not working - does not update the UI at all
    self.root = state
    # 2. crashing on __init__
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root = stateText
    self.root.__init__()
    # 3: Nope.. not updates the state either.
    self.root.update()

root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
```

does it even possible to do it this way?
the reason I do it like this it's because my app is quite big in if I could make this method work I could save and load the state of any tkinter app with ease without being worried if I forgot something...

also tried some recursive functions that call to `__init__` method of each child but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> does it even possible to do it this way?

No, it is not. Tkinter widgets exist as C objects in an embedded tcl interpreter. There is no way to save and restore the state of an embedded tcl interpreter.

Comment: so how can i achive this? by manuly create custom save  and load foramat?\

Comment: You will have to write code that saves all of the configuration options and data for every widget, and then at startup you'll have to create the widgets and restore all of the configuration options and data. There's no automatic way to do it.